# How to update uber cart attribute pricing programatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

I am using the following code to alter a price, but after being saved, and viewing the node, I don't see any changes.

```
$node = node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($node->attributes[4]->options as $attribute) {
    $attribute->price = 4363;
}
node_save($node);
```

I suspect the problem either being how I am trying to update, or perhaps some caching issue.

*UPDATE*

I fixed this by running a straight forward SQL query:

```
UPDATE uc_product_options set price = 333 where oid = 111
```

But it would still be nice to know how to do this the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE uc_product_options set price = 333 where oid = 111
```